# Callback functions from kaltura HTML5 video

Tags: html, html5-video

Can anybody help me how to call video callback functions from kaltura HTML5 video player.

Answer (score 0):

Kaltura's html5 video library maps directly to the W3C spec so you can use standard media/audio/video callbacks:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#media-element